# Dictation in Mac OS doesn’t leave spaces between words in Emacs

Tags: osx, text-editing

I have tried to use the dictation feature of Mac OS in Emacs and it works quite well, except that it doesn’t seem to recognise spaces between words if I pause shortly and also omits spaces between sentences. Example:

> This is a testAnd dictation in Emacs. It seems like spaces are omittedIf you use the dictation Feature.Is this possible to solve?

Reading [this answer on apple.stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201389/how-can-i-fix-missing-spaces-when-using-dictation-with-macvim-or-terminal) it seems like it has to do with the interaction between the feature in the OS and the application, in this case Emacs.

Comment: Maybe emacs macport would be better for this case. It usually has better support for mac related features.

Comment: I have this version: `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) of 2015-04-10 on builder10-9.porkrind.org`

Comment: What does Emacs receive when you dictate? What is the output of `C-h l` after a dictate? If you would like to debug this, you can uncomment the line in nsterm.m that defined NSTRACE_ENABLED (if I remember correctly), recompile Emacs, run it in a terminal window and look at the trace output to see what Emacs receives.

Comment: I'm seeing spaces correctly inserted in both my stock versions of emacs and vim on 10.12.X and 10.11.X. Enhanced Dictation determines if it should add a space before the recognized utterance by inspecting the character before the insertion point via its IMKInputController connection to the text. Seems like it's not getting access to the preceding characters. Does this happen on the Terminal command line as well?

Comment: @JustSomeMacDude It works fine in Terminal.app

Comment: @Lindydancer I’m sorry, but this is somewhat above my skill level. Without pretty specific instructions I’m not sure I can manage to do what you’re asking.

Comment: I do use Enhanced Dictation, by the way. @JustSomeMacDude

Answer (score 1):

I have the same behavior when editing code, but not in fundamental mode (`M-x fundamental-mode`).

Probably some language-specific mechanism is interfering, but other than that there doesn't appear a fundamental flaw in Emacs' Dictation integration.